# 2 lines of reading and one array element append

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

How could I solve it simply and great?

First 6 line of input file (170 lines and the shape is still the same):

```
6 1 0 6 2 25
392712621
6 13 31 6 18 15
442407028
6 29 39 6 34 7
712676212
```

I want to put it to an array like this

```
[[6, 1, 0, 6, 2, 25, 392712621], [6, 13, 31, 6, 18, 15, 442407028], [6, 29, 39, 6, 34, 7, 712676212]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
outputs = []
for i in range(3):
    inputs = list(map(int, input().split()))
    inputs.append(int(input()))
    outputs.append(inputs)
print(outputs)
```

Change the number inside range to half the number of lines you need to parse.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include the explanation, instead of leaving it as a comment.